# How to delete the last occurrence of a function name (e.g. "cos" or "ln" or "tan") in a calculator edittext with one click?

Tags: android

I wanted to delete the last occurrence of a function name in a calculator edittext with one click.
I already have a delete button, which looks like this:

```
private void onDelete() {
    final Editable formulaText = mFormulaEditText.getEditableText();
    final int formulaLength = formulaText.length();
    if (formulaLength > 0) {
        formulaText.delete(formulaLength - 1, formulaLength);
    }
}
```

I tried to get the last 3 character than if it equals with the function name, delete 3 letters, but the problem is that there are some longer (e.g.: atanh) or shorter function names (e.g.: ln).

P. S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Make a loop and replace all the function names (previously stored in an array) with "". EASY. Or use some regular expression (less easy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
private static String removeLastMathFunction(String input) {
    final String mathFnRegex = "(ln|log|a?(sin|cos|tan)h?)";
    final String lastMathFnRegex = mathFnRegex + "(?!.*" + mathFnRegex + ")";
    return input.replaceAll(lastMathFnRegex, "");
}

private void onDelete() {
    String oldInputValue = mFormulaEditText.getText().toString();
    String newInputValue = removeLastMathFunction(oldInputValue);
    mFormulaEditText.setText(newInputValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it removes all function names, not just the last one (e.g. "120*tan(3*tan(2))")
So i just wanted to remove the last function name. Can you help how can i reach this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are the best!